# Fastest way to check if a string can be parsed

Tags: c#, .net, performance, parsing, exception

I am parsing CSV files to lists of objects with strongly-typed properties.  This involves parsing each string value from the file to an `IConvertible` type (`int`, `decimal`, `double`, `DateTime`, etc) using `TypeDescriptor`.

I am using a `try catch` to handle situations when parsing fails.  The exact details of where and why this exception occurs is then logged for further investigation.  Below is the actually parsing code:

```
try
{
    parsedValue = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type).ConvertFromString(dataValue);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Log failure
}
```

**Problem:**

When values are successfully parsed, the process is quick.  When parsing data with lots of invalid data, the process can take thousands of times slower (due to catching the exception).

I've been testing this with parsing to `DateTime`.  These are the performance figures:

- Successful parsing: average of **32 ticks** per parse
- Failed parsing: average of **146296 ticks** per parse

That's more than 4500 times slower.

**Question:**

Is it possible for me to check to see if a string value can be successfully parsed without having to use my expensive `try catch` method?  Or perhaps there is another way I should be doing this?

**EDIT:  I need to use `TypeDescriptor` (and not `DateTime.TryParse`) because the type is determined at runtime.**

Comment: If you know the `type`, you _could_ try manually hitting each one's various `TryParse` methods and see if that helps.

Comment: Are you trying to hit every type parser in order to see which one is compatible for the CSV entry? That is, first you try `DateTime`, then you try `int`, then you try `decimal`, then you try `double`, then catch-all to `string`? Or do you _know_ that a certain entry _should_ be `DateTime`, but sometimes/often the data itself is in an incorrect format?

Comment: Also, are you performing this benchmarking in `release` mode or `debug` mode, or with the debugger attached? If in `debug` mode, it may be reporting/storing excessive exception/stack information for debugging purposes.

Comment: @Chris:  I am not hitting every type parser.  At run-time I know the type to convert too but, yes, sometimes the data could be in the incorrect format.

Comment: @Chris: I am performing this in debug mode.  I could test it in release mode but I don't suspect that it would be magnitudes faster?

Comment: It might be a bit faster, especially if you are throwing _a lot_ of exceptions. Do you have a fixed number of supported types? Like you only support `DateTime`, `int`, `double`, `decimal`, `string`, and some others? Or is the list of supported types unknown at compile-time?

Comment: @Chris: All [IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx) types, so essentially Boolean, Byte, Integer, Single, Double, Decimal, DateTime, Char and String.

Comment: It should be quite a lot (magnitudes, possibly) faster if you run it without the debugger attached (i.e. Ctrl+F5). The debugger does *lots* of stuff when an exception is thrown.

Comment: You'd think Microsoft would natively support this in the framework wouldn't you?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have a known set of types to convert, you can do a series of `if/elseif/elseif/else` (or `switch/case` on the type name) to essentially distribute it to specialized parsing methods. This should be pretty fast. This is as described in [@Fabio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16835901/1269654).

If you still have performance issues, you can also create a lookup table which will let you add new parsing methods as you need to support them:

Given some basic parsing wrappers:

```
public delegate bool TryParseMethod<T>(string input, out T value);

public interface ITryParser
{
    bool TryParse(string input, out object value);
}

public class TryParser<T> : ITryParser
{
    private TryParseMethod<T> ParsingMethod;

    public TryParser(TryParseMethod<T> parsingMethod)
    {
        this.ParsingMethod = parsingMethod;
    }

    public bool TryParse(string input, out object value)
    {
        T parsedOutput;
        bool success = ParsingMethod(input, out parsedOutput);
        value = parsedOutput;
        return success;
    }
}
```

You can then setup a conversion helper which does the lookup and calls the appropriate parser:

```
public static class DataConversion
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, ITryParser> Parsers;

    static DataConversion()
    {
        Parsers = new Dictionary<Type, ITryParser>();
        AddParser<DateTime>(DateTime.TryParse);
        AddParser<int>(Int32.TryParse);
        AddParser<double>(Double.TryParse);
        AddParser<decimal>(Decimal.TryParse);
        AddParser<string>((string input, out string value) => {value = input; return true;});
    }

    public static void AddParser<T>(TryParseMethod<T> parseMethod)
    {
        Parsers.Add(typeof(T), new TryParser<T>(parseMethod));
    }

    public static bool Convert<T>(string input, out T value)
    {
        object parseResult;
        bool success = Convert(typeof(T), input, out parseResult);
        if (success)
            value = (T)parseResult;
        else
            value = default(T);
        return success;
    }

    public static bool Convert(Type type, string input, out object value)
    {
        ITryParser parser;
        if (Parsers.TryGetValue(type, out parser))
            return parser.TryParse(input, out value);
        else
            throw new NotSupportedException(String.Format("The specified type \"{0}\" is not supported.", type.FullName));
    }
}
```

Then usage might be like:

```
//for a known type at compile time
int value;
if (!DataConversion.Convert<int>("3", out value))
{
    //log failure
}

//or for unknown type at compile time:
object value;
if (!DataConversion.Convert(myType, dataValue, out value))
{
    //log failure
}
```

This could probably have the generics expanded on to avoid `object` boxing and type casting, but as it stands this works fine; perhaps only optimize that aspect if you have a measurable performance from it.

EDIT: You can update the `DataConversion.Convert` method so that if it doesn't have the specified converter registered, it can fall-back to your `TypeConverter` method or throw an appropriate exception. It's up to you if you want to have a catch-all or simply have your predefined set of supported types and avoid having your `try/catch` all over again. As it stands, the code has been updated to throw a `NotSupportedException` with a message indicating the unsupported type. Feel free to tweak as it makes sense. Performance wise, maybe it makes sense to do the catch-all as perhaps those will be fewer and far between once you specify specialized parsers for the most commonly used types.

Comment: Good, but you should use `Parsers.TryGetValue` and fallback to the `TypeConverter` and exception-handling for unanticipated types.

Comment: @BenVoigt Funny, I was _just_ adding that. I started doing the `TypeConverter` method but I figured that would be missing the point of this. davenewza specified that he has a fixed number of types and wanted to avoid the `try/catch` exception handling in the first place.

Comment: Excellent solution Chris.  I completely forgot that I also need to cater for `Nullable` types.  Would it be possible with your solution... `Nullable<int>` perhaps?  I will attempt this now myself.

Comment: I have implemented my own static `TryParse` methods for `Nullable` types as per your `TryParserMethod` delegate.  Works perfectly and it is VERY fast.

Comment: @davenewza Glad it worked out for you. It should be _very_ flexible. You can feed it your own delegates for custom types or even implement your own `ITryParser` classes if you have very complicated logic or even wanted to expand on some of the primitive type conversions (e.g., support "true/false", "1/0", "Yes/No" for booleans). EDIT: You can even expand on the `ITryParser` definition to support say, custom error messages or reasons that you can't parse it.

Answer (score 7):

If you know a type where you trying to parse, then use TryParse method:

```
String value;
Int32 parsedValue;
if (Int32.TryParse(value, parsedValue) == True)
    // actions if parsed ok
else
    // actions if not parsed
```

Same for other types

```
Decimal.TryParse(value, parsedValue)
Double.TryParse(value, parsedValue)
DateTime.TryParse(value, parsedValue)
```

Or you can use next workaround:

Create a parse methods for every type with same name, but different signature(wrap TryParse inside of them):

```
Private bool TryParsing(String value, out Int32 parsedValue)
{
    Return Int32.TryParse(value, parsedValue)
}

Private bool TryParsing(String value, out Double parsedValue)
{
    Return Double.TryParse(value, parsedValue)
}

Private bool TryParsing(String value, out Decimal parsedValue)
{
    Return Decimal.TryParse(value, parsedValue)
}

Private bool TryParsing(String value, out DateTime parsedValue)
{
    Return DateTime.TryParse(value, parsedValue)
}
```

Then you can use method `TryParsing` with your types

Comment: So would you recommend that I perform type checking and then run the relevant `TryParse` method?

Comment: @davenewza Yes, if you have a fixed number of supported types. If necessary, you can move the "type checking" to say a lookup table keyed by `Type` and its value is some kind of parser or delegate.

Comment: There is only one `Type` object for each unique type, so you can compare them with `ReferenceEquals`, which is comparing object references, which should be very fast compared to catching exceptions.

Comment: @davenewza, because you have fixed number of used types, then I think better will be yo write Parse/Checking methods for every type...

Comment: @Moo-Juice, sorry was writing first VB.NET code, then after trying to change to C# :) - updated...

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `TryParse` method :

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(input, out dateTime))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
}
```

Comment: I need to be able to parse to any type, hence why I need to use TypeDescriptor.  Edited post!

Comment: what if you covert your object to string first with toString() and than use that :), Keep us posted about your findings so we can learn the fastest way to parse :)

Answer (score 2):

How about constructing a regular expression for each type and applying it to the string before calling Parse?  You'd have to build the regular expression such that if the string doesn't match, it wouldn't parse.  This would be a little slower if the string parses since you'd have to do the regex test, but it would be way faster if it doesn't parse.

You could put the regex strings in a `Dictionary<Type, string>`, which would make determining which regex string to use simple.

Comment: That is a good idea.  The only problem is that this needs to be culture-sensitive.  So, depending on the culture settings, it would parse differently.  Decimal points, for example, could be a point or a comma.

Comment: Then you'd have to write logic to build the regex strings using the current culture settings.  Everything you need is in that object.  At least it's something you'd only have to do at initialization time and maybe if the culture settings change.

Comment: *You'd have to build the regular expression such that if the string doesn't match, it wouldn't parse.* That's a lot harder than it sounds. The Regex to parse *valid* `byte` values is surprisingly involved. If you insist on using Regex, you're better off using them to pre-filter the obviously bad stuff, but still handle exceptions that might arise with `Parse`.

Comment: @JimMischel:  Agreed, the exception handling is required if you're going to use `Parse.`

Comment: Have a problem? Try using `Regex`. Now you have two problems.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you're using a DateTime, you can always use the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) function. This will be a magnitude faster.

Comment: I need to be able to parse to any type, hence why I need to use TypeDescriptor.  Edited post!

Comment: you could use TryParse methods for known types, and call TypeDescritor for other ones.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way to check if something can be parsed from a string would be to check if the type implements [`<IParsable<>>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iparsable-1?view=net-8.0).

```cs
// Assuming we have a variable called myType of type <Type>

bool canBeParsed = type.GetInterface(typeof(IParsable<>).Name) is not null;
```

This way we know we can access [`.Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iparsable-1.parse?view=net-8.0#system-iparsable-1-parse(system-string-system-iformatprovider)) from any instance by casting it to [`<IParsable<>>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iparsable-1?view=net-8.0).